# Testing interactive artisan commands using Mockey

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-artisan, mockery

I am writing unit tests for interactive commands in Laravel 5.3 following this [guide](https://themsaid.com/building-testing-interactive-console-20160409) but I can't seem to get Mockery to work.

I've set up a simple command, [greet:user](https://github.com/mtvbrianking/test-artisan-command/blob/master/app/Console/Commands/GreetUser.php).

```
public function handle()
{
    if(!$name = $this->argument('name')) {
        $name = $this->ask('Name of user to greet');
    }

    $this->info("Hello {$name}.");
}
```

And am writing [unit-tests](https://github.com/mtvbrianking/test-artisan-command/blob/master/tests/Commands/GreetUserTest.php) like;

```
public function testCanGreetGivenUser()
{
    $command = Mockery::mock('App\Console\Commands\GreetUser[info]');

    $command->shouldReceive('info')->once()->with('Hello Brian.');

    $exit_code = Artisan::call('greet:user', ['name' => 'Brian', '--no-interaction' => true]);
    $this->assertEquals(trim(Artisan::output()), 'Hello Brian.');
    $this->assertEquals($exit_code, 0);
}
```

**Issue:**

`Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method info("Hello Brian.") from Mockery_0_App_Console_Commands_GreetUser should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

My goal is to test;

**If no input expected**

```
$this->artisan('greet:user', ['name' => 'Brian'])
    ->expectsOutput('Hello Brian.')
    ->assertExitCode(0);
```

**If input is required.**

```
$this->artisan('greet:user')
    ->expectsQuestion('Name of user to greet', 'James')
    ->expectsOutput('Hello James.')
    ->assertExitCode(0);
```

That's how I could do it in Laravel 5.7, but how can I achieve the same for Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you'll have to call the test as follows:

```
public function testCanGreetGivenUser()
{
    $command = Mockery::mock('\App\Console\Commands\GreetUser[info]');

    $command->shouldReceive('info')->once()->with('Hello Brian.');

    $this->app[\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class]->registerCommand($command);

    $exit_code = $this->artisan('greet:user', ['name' => 'Brian', '--no-interaction' => true]);
    $this->assertEquals($exit_code, 0);
}
```

The deciding factor is the command registration. You must do it to actually replace the existing instance of the command with your mock.

Comment: I've given it sometime but I just can't get it to work. Themsaid explains it here: https://themsaid.com/building-testing-interactive-console-20160409 but am stuck.

Comment: It is essential for you to use the `artisan` method on the TestCase class and to mock the console Kernel. Using the Artisan facade will circumvent the mocked instances.

Comment: Do you mind helping me out? I created a simple repo to demonstrate this. https://github.com/mtvbrianking/test-artisan-command

Comment: I'll take a look and post a pull request.

Comment: I'd appreciate that. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried to make it work with the 5.7 version of the console tests, but you'd have to change so many files, I think it's not worth it. Check the corrected answer for the working solution (per the guide you sent).